# Svg line strange effect on bottom-border

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser

Someone say me if a `svg` line makes a strange effect on border-bottom ?

[image]

I have this html:

```
 <div id="father">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" style="transform: rotate(360deg);background: #34495e;">
    <path fill-opacity="1" d="M0,224L60,208C120,192,240,160,360,138.7C480,117,600,107,720,138.7C840,171,960,245,1080,245.3C1200,245,1320,171,1380,133.3L1440,96L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z" fill="#e4f1fe"></path>
  </svg>
  <div id="subsling"></div>
  <!-- This line appears and disappears depending on the size of the browser window. -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Indeed there is a small space between the svg element and the next div. You may add`display:block;` to the svg element

Comment: @enxaneta It already has those properties but nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've commented: add `svg{display:block;}`
 to the svg

```css
svg{width:100%;display:block;}
#subsling{background: #e4f1fe;padding:1em;}
```

```html
<div id="father">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" style="transform: rotate(360deg);background: #34495e;">
          <path fill-opacity="1" d="M0,224L60,208C120,192,240,160,360,138.7C480,117,600,107,720,138.7C840,171,960,245,1080,245.3C1200,245,1320,171,1380,133.3L1440,96L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z" fill="#e4f1fe"></path>
</svg>  
 <div id="subsling">
   <p>wertyui wertyuio ertyufghjklñ  ertyuiop eghjkl </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing, the line appears and disappears

Comment: In this case you have to update your question and add an example where this is happening

Comment: i should add the same image ?